# How to bind data-src attribute for the image in the post using jquery?

Tags: plugin-development, jquery, javascript

I'm trying to use [foresight.js](https://github.com/adamdbradley/foresight.js) for responsive image in the wordpress blog. For that I have to add the `data-src` attribute in the place of `src` in the `<img>` tag.

Or I have to get the url from the image in the post and need to bind my new  tag near the old `<img>` tag and wrap that old `<img>` tag in `<noscript>` tag. I don't have any idea how to do it.

Basically it must looks like this:

```
<img data-src="http://foresightjs.appspot.com/dynamic-images/px-wright-flyer.jpg" data-aspect-ratio="auto" class="fs-img">
<noscript>
    <img src="http://foresightjs.appspot.com/dynamic-images/1024px-wright-flyer.jpg">
</noscript>
```